# Restore Thunderbird's look/interface?

Tags: thunderbird, gui, user-interface

I have two computers running the same version of Thunderbird. One uses an old, 5+ years, installation and looks like TB always did but on the other machine, where I made a new installation a few weeks ago, it looks and behaves completely different.

Googling *restore Thunderbird interface* and similar just returned results about Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1186491

Furthermore, "quote selection when responding" doesn't work on my new installation either and I can't find any setting for that.

How do I restore TB's old and ugly, but functional, look?

[image: New Thunderbird look]

Comment: Your partial screen shot doesn't look familiar.  Please provide more context with a larger section of screen.

Comment: It was an extension, that had auto-updated itself. Grr...